# How can I set the dayjs to empty? in Vue and KendoUI

Tags: vue.js, kendo-ui, dayjs, kendo-datepicker

I'm making a search box using Vue and KendoUI.
I want to set my DatePicker to empty at first.
If necessary, I would like to enter a value and I need to get formatted value.(e.g.,YYYYMMDD)

1. The input at the start should be empty.
2. When entering a value, the return value must be formatted.
3. don't use Jquery

Thank you for reading it

//can't get formatted value

```
<template>
<kendo-datepicker
    v-model="test.day"
    :format="'yyyy-MM-dd'"
    :parse-formats="['yyyyMMdd']"
></kendo-datepicker>
</template>
.....
<script>
.....
    data: function() {
        return {
            test: {
                day: "",
            },
        };
    },
.....
</script>
```

//I want to set value to empty.

```
<template>
<kendo-datepicker
    v-model="test.day"
    :format="'yyyy-MM-dd'"
    :parse-formats="['yyyyMMdd']"
></kendo-datepicker>
</template>
.....
<script>
.....
    data: function() {
        return {
            test: {
                day: dayjs().format("YYYYMMDD"), 
            },
        };
    },
.....
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

have you tried using:

```
$("#datepicker").val('')
```

I think these two questions are similar to yours and would help to read through them, so I am sharing them here.

- [Set datepicker value to empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48513713/set-datepicker-value-to-empty)
- [How to replace a default date with an empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40927520/how-to-replace-a-default-date-with-an-empty-string)